# What's the difference between "have been" and "would have been"?

Tags: word-usage

Is there any difference between have been and would have been? Please also provide sample sentences if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**would** is a past form of the modal verb **will**. **would have been** means something in the past **would have** happened if or if not something in the past (before that event) happened. For example;

> *Without your advice*, I **would have been** robbed of my bag.

**would have been** implies something that **could have been** did not happen because of some reason.

However, **have been**, as in the following sentence;

> I **have been** robbed of my bag. I wish someone advised me not to go there.

The event / action in **have been** part has occurred, and could have been avoided if warned of.